# How to apply system theme to flatpak apps that use GTK4?

Tags: 20.04, themes, gtk3, flatpak, gtk4

I use one of default themes - Yaru-dark Gtk Theme. I installed it via flatpak as well. The application id is `org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark`. Some apps that I installed via flatpak follow it, but others do. I noticed, that apps that do not follow it use Gtk4 & libadwaita, so that might be the cause. Is there a way to make also the other apps use the system theme? I tried looking for `org.gtk.Gtk4theme.Yaru-dark` on flathub, but there is none.

```
$ flatpak remote-ls flathub | grep -i yaru-dark
Yaru-dark Gtk Theme org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark     3.22
```

For example [baobab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/baobab/) uses gtk4 and does not follow the system theme, while [mypaint](https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint) uses gtk3 and follows the system theme.

[image: baobab]
[image: mypaint]

Answer (score 8):

As of now, the flatpak Gtk4 apps only support `Adwaita`, `Adwaita-Dark` and `Yaru-*` (if installed) themes, but there is a workaround.

You can set all GTK-4 apps to use it. To do that, you need to set the theme for non-flatpak GTK3 and GTK4 apps and for flatpak apps using GTK3 and GTK4.

**Non-flatpak GTK-3 apps**

Use gnome-tweaks. Change it in the appearance section.

**Non-flatpak GTK-4 apps**

Set an option in your theme's installer to use `libAdawita`. The theme that I use (Orchis) has this option. If it doesn't, or does not have an installer, copy the files in `~/.themes/[Your-Theme]/gtk-4`/ or `/usr/share/themes/[Your-Theme]/gtk-4.0/` (where `Your-Theme` is the name of your theme) to `~/.config/gtk-4.0/`. You'll have to override the default Adawita stuff there, so back it up if you're concerned.

**Flatpak GTK-3 apps**

Install your theme from Flathub:

```
flatpak install org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark
```

*(in this example, we use Yaru-dark)*

If your theme is not not on Flathub (it likely isn't), you can use these commands to allow them to read the folders, and use your theme.

```
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.themes/
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.icons/
```

*(the latter command will also allow them to use your icon and cursor packs)*

**Flatpak GTK-4 apps**

Give apps permissions to access it and set the `GTK_THEME` environment variable for them. I used [flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal), but it can be done via `flatpak` cli.

The `/usr/share/themes/` folder is blacklisted in Flatpak, so that can't be set. I've tried symlinks, but they don't work. You have to copy (or move) the theme to `~/.themes/` or another folder you store your themes in.

```
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.themes/
sudo flatpak override --env GTK_THEME=Yaru-Dark
```

Answer (score 3):

As users, we need a little patience sometimes. Ubuntu creates Yaru, and Ubuntu creates Snap. For Snap packages, they adopted to have the Yaru appearance for apps that use libadwaita (GTK4). Had they adopted Flatpak instead, it would already work for Flatpak.

[We are not this far yet](https://github.com/flathub/org.gnome.Extensions/issues/9#issuecomment-933375301). This is Free Software, so once someone creates the flatpak, it will work.

Comment: Snap/Flatpak takes the burden off the developers - you can't implement code for most of the distros - but it breaks the consistent theming.  As a developer, I welcome Snap, as a user, I despise it. And even now - snap is one of many (fedora is using flatpak). One of the reasons why linux will not succeed in conquering the desktop [See Linus Torwalts rant about distros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pzl1B7nB9Kc)